# Dirichlet convolution of Mobius function with exponential function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function, dirichlet-convolution

Define $\exp_x : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\exp_x(d) = e^{ixd}$ for all $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to evaluate the Dirichlet convolution of the Mobius function $\mu$ with $\exp_x$,
$$
f(x,n) := (\exp_x * \mu)(n) = \sum_{d | n} \mu\left(d\right) e^{ixn/d}.
$$
Since $\exp_x$ is not multiplicative, it's not obvious to me what to do. Is there a trick for computing a sum like this?

Of course, an obvious thing to try is to Taylor expand $f$ about $x = 0$, which gives
$$
f(x, n) = \left\lfloor \frac{1}{n} \right\rfloor + \sum_{k \geq 1}\frac{(ixn)^k}{k!}\sum_{d|n} \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)d^{-k}.
$$
*Now* the divisor sum is multiplicative, so it's not too hard to show that
$$
\sum_{d|n} \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)d^{-k} = \frac{1}{n^k}\prod_{p | n} \left(1-p^k\right) = \frac{(-1)^{\omega(n)} \text{rad}^k(n)J_k(n)}{n^{2k}},
$$
where $J_k(n)$ is the Jordan totient function, $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors $p$ of $n$, and $\text{rad}(n)$ is the radical of the integer $n$. Thus,
$$
f(x, n) = \left\lfloor \frac{1}{n} \right\rfloor + \sum_{k \geq 1}\frac{(ixn)^k}{k!}\frac{(-1)^{\omega(n)} \text{rad}^k(n)J_k(n)}{n^{2k}},
$$
but I have no clue where to go from here (assuming a closed form even exists).

Comment: When $x = 2\pi a/q$ there is a simplification with Dirichlet characters $\bmod q$.

Comment: @reuns : That's true, though obviously much more restrictive than I want to be. I appreciate the comment though

Comment: Also $\mu(n)e^{2i\pi nx} \ast 1$ is more interesting than $\mu(n)\ast e^{2i\pi nx}$, what are you trying to do?